# Store CSV column and Rows as php variable

Tags: php, csv, generator

I have a semi-large CSV file with 2,000 rows and about 25 columns. 
I need to know how to convert the cells to a variable. If even possible. IE convert cell A3 to a php variable then which I can echo out when a user clicks a button. Sort of a Generator I'm making.

I could not find anything of real use on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for this: [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). You use it to return the next line in the file resource (and then advance the pointer). It will return an array where each element is a field in the CSV.

You would use it like this:

```
$csv = array();

if (FALSE !== $handle = fopen("example.csv", "r"))
{

  while (FALSE !== $row = fgetcsv($handle))
  {
    $csv[] = $row;
  }

}
```

You can then do something like the following, assuming that the first row in the CSV contains the column headers, to convert the numeric array into an associative array:

```
$new_csv = array();

foreach ($csv as $row)
{

  $new_row = array();

  for ($i = 0, $n = count($csv[0]); $i < $n; ++$i)
  {
    $new_row[$csv[0][$i]] = $row[$i]; 
  }

  $new_csv[] = $new_row;

}
```

Then, if you want to access the "name" column of the first row (where the "zeroth" row is the column headers), you'd call `$new_csv[1]['name']`. Alternatively, if there is no header row, and you know that the "name" column is the first column, you'd call `$csv[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) methods (see links for examples).